# Erro cron Laravel não executa

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, cron

Tenho um cron que dever ser executando todo dia em uma hora.

$schedule->command('inspire')->dailyAt('15:00');

porém ele não esta sendo executado

**Codigo**

```
<?php

namespace App\Units;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel;
use App\Console\Commands\EnvioEmailBlCron;

class ConsoleKernel extends Kernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [

        \App\Console\Commands\EnvioEmailBICron::class 
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule $schedule
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        //configuração do cron
        $schedule->command('inspire')->dailyAt('15:00'); 
        $schedule->command('envioemailbicron:cron')->daily(); // email diários
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
    }
}
```

Comando sendo executado no cmd:

> php artisan envioemailbicron:cron

Comment: Não é este commando. O comando para executar é `php artisan schedule:run`, este comando deverá executar no tempo configurado os comandos que estão listados na função `schedule`

Comment: recebo esta mensagem: No scheduled commands are ready to run.

Comment: Oxe, pois não tem. Veja que uma esta configurado para ser executado apenas as 15:00, e outra todo dia a meia noite.

Comment: como registro meu comando ?

Comment: Seu comando já está registrado. Você agendou dois comandos para serem executadas, o que você precisa fazer é colocar o comando `php artisan schedule:run` para ser rodado a cada minuto na cron.

Comment: como faço isso ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398014/using-crontab-to-execute-script-every-minute-and-another-every-24-hours

Comment: inserir o comondo aqui :  protected $commands = []

Comment: erro ainda persiste !

Comment: Que erro que persiste? Não tem erro nenhum.

Comment: No scheduled commands are ready to run.

Comment: Já disse. Não tem comandos para ser executado agora. Você determinou que o comando `inspire` seja executado todo dia AS 15:00 HORAS, AGORA NÃO SÃO 15 horas, e o outro comando, determinou que seja executado todo dia A MEIA NOITE, agora também não é meia noite.

Comment: alterei o horário para 15:20, 15:30 e 16:00, 16:20, 16:30 e nada foi executado

Comment: continua exibindo a mensagem: No scheduled commands are ready to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta isso

```
$schedule->command('envioemailbicron:cron')->everyMinute();
```

Comment: No scheduled commands are ready to run

Comment: o erro ainda persiste

Comment: Onde posso registrar o o comando ?

Comment: Editei minha resposta

Comment: afinal, você quer executar qual comando? inspire ou envioemailbicron:cron?

Comment: os dois comandos: Inspire e envioemailbicron

Comment: Insipre para agenda o envio diario

Answer (score 0):

Para executar o comando Inspire você precisa adicionar ele no kernel..

```
protected $commands = [

    \App\Console\Commands\EnvioEmailBICron::class,
    \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,


];
```

Se o seu comando Inspire estiver no caminho padrão, é só adicionar isso em seu protected

Comment: apos ser executado o comando no terminal: ele fica em loop ??

Comment: dever executar o comando apos executar o crom (24h/1h/minuto) ??

Comment: o comando que passei antes executa a cada minuto

Comment: cara, da uma olhada no manual do laravel, está bem detalhado, não tem dificuldade de entender lá

Comment: ...eternamente ??